# File path pointing to variable in bash script

Tags: bash, file, variables, curl, certificate

I wonder if it is possible provide instead of file path file content itself. For example `curl` needs to specify file path to certificate. What to do when I have a certificate in variable?
I can't put it into stdin, because I'm generating xml to send there.

Why I put certificate into variable? Because at the end I'd like to have just one file with script, which can I easily distribute to my colleagues.

The only solution which come to my mind is to save variable to file and then provide file path to `curl`

```
read -d '' CERT << "CERTEND"
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
### something very secret here ###
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
CERTEND

curl -# -k --cert ??? -d @xml.xml -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" -H 'SOAPAction: ""' https://1.1.1.1/EndpointPort`
```

Comment: save it. use `mktemp` or `tempfile`

Comment: Thank you, this works good: `CERT_FILE=$(mktemp) || { echo "Failed to create cert_file"; exit 1; }` and `echo "${MUJ_CERT}"  > $CERT_FILE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution:

```
curl --cert <(echo "$CERT") ...
```

which would create a pipe for you. The output of the command in parentheses goes to this pipe (`echo $CERT` in our case), and the filename of the pipe is returned.

Comment: I try and get `curl: (58) Unable to load certificate /proc/self/fd/63` I also try `<(echo "${CERT}")` but no success

Comment: @lojza - I have no certificate to try it, but I've tested it with `-d` switch like this: `curl -d @<(echo "$CERT") URL` and confirmed with `tcpdump` that it's indeed working - contents of `CERT` variable are being sent. Is it working when you save the file with certificate and put the path to `--cert` switch?

Comment: Did you get certificate to be loaded? Switch `-d` works fine for me too. Maybe there is a problem that I'm  using certificate with pasword and separate key: `some stuff | curl -# -k --cert ???:pass --key ??? -d @- -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" -H 'SOAPAction: ""' https://1.1.1.1/EndpointPort` Anyway I try lot of combinations (echo only cert, only key, quotes, brackets...) and still no success. Even so thank you for your help.